# Running some Rails code when the database is updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

What is the cleanest way of running some Rails code when a certain database table is updated (not necessarily by my program)? The event hook doesn't have to be written in Ruby, but It'd be nice to reuse some of my Rails code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be an Active Record [callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#callbacks-overview).

> Callbacks are methods that get called at certain moments of an object’s life cycle. With callbacks it is possible to write code that will run whenever an Active Record object is created, saved, updated, deleted, validated, or loaded from the database.

Comment: Will a callback be called if some other program modifies the database?

Comment: No. In this case, you'll have to implement it with triggers inside of your database. But I wouldn't recommend you to make other programs communicate directly with your database, you could implement a REST API for that.

Comment: It really depends on your requirements. But, as I see it, it's better to have a bunch of modules that communicates through webservices than to have each module communicates directly via database. There are times when this is not always possible, though. In this case, the right way is through triggers. The disadvantage on using triggers is that they don't have a minimal architeture. They are just functions thrown inside of the database.